# Group of 4 elements (beginner question)

Tags: group-theory

First of all - I deeply apologize for my mathematical English, it's not my native language nor I study math on it...

I am really stuck here... I have the following question on my entry level math course:

Let G be a group of 4 elements (doesn't specified if they distinct from each other) relative to binary operation Δ. Given that *e* is an identity element and *a* is element in G that is not inverse to itself (i.e = *a Δ a ≠ e*).

I need to prove that there are element *x* in G such as *x ≠ e* and that *x* is inverse to itself - *x Δ x = e*.

What I did is showed that if *a* is not inverse to itself, then, according to group theory rules, there is *b* in G that is inverse to *a* and also not *e*. Now I showed that there are 3 elements, *a,b,e* and I need to prove that there is *x* in G that satisfies the original request. I pointed to *x = a Δ a* and proved that *a Δ a ≠ e*, that *a Δ a ≠ a*, but I cannot show that *a Δ a ≠ b*.

Anyone have any ideas?..

Comment: I can, but I need to show first that x = a Δ a ≠ a-1, so I will point to a distinct element. Or am I missing something?..

Comment: @A.G That is what I did - I assumed that *x = aΔa*  But they didn't mentioned 4 **different** elements - just 4 elements. If they would say that they are different, then I would state that *aΔa* cannot be *a-1*, since *a* already has inverse element, that must be distinct to every element in the group. So I showed that aΔa* is not *e* and not *a*, but I cannot manage to show that it's not *a-1*...

Answer (score 1):

Inverses come in pairs, $a,a^{-1}$. $e$ is its own inverse, so there are 3 elements left, at least one must be paired with itself.

Comment: Yes, that is what I did. I just noticed that I didn't wrote that b is a−1. So a, a−1, e - and I am looking to show the 4th.

Comment: @Uplink:  in fact, it is $a^2$, but you don't need that.  All you need is that there is a fourth element.  Its inverse cannot be $a, a^{-1},$ or $e$, so it must be itself.  This proof works for any group with an even number of elements-there must be a non-identity element that is its own inverse.

Comment: @RossMillikan that is what I am trying to show, that aΔa cannot be a-1 or (aΔa)-1 cannot be a. Just can't figure out, every equation that I try leads me to total mess...

Comment: If $a \Delta a=a^{-1}$, then $a \Delta a \Delta a=e$ but we know the order of $a$ divides $4$ from Lagrange's theorem.

Comment: @RossMillikan I wish that I could use that, but unfortunately it's not in that course material :( So I just, like you, came to *aΔaΔa=e*, but have nothing to do with that in my case...

Comment: Then call your elements $e,a,a^{-1},b$ and assume $a\Delta a =a^{-1}$.  Then what is $a \Delta b$?.  It can't be $a,b,e$, so must be $a^{-1}$, but then $b=a^{-1} \Delta a \Delta b=a^{-1} \Delta a^{-1}=a$, contradiction

Comment: @RossMillikan There is a problem with assumption that *aΔb* can't be *e*, since I need to prove before that *b ≠ a-1*... :( And that is what I am looking for :)

Comment: @A.G the set has exactly 4 elements and is a group for operation Δ. Given *e* element as an identity, and *a* that is not inverse to itself (i.e = a Δ a ≠ e). I need to prove that there is element *x* that is NOT *e* and is inverse to itself (x Δ x = e). So according to a group rules, I proved that there is a inverse to *a*, now I need to show that there is *x* in G according to the above request.

Comment: You can't have $a\Delta b=e$ because then $b=a^{-1}$ and we chose it to be the element that isn't $e,a,a^{-1}$

Comment: @A.G Y has 1 element (we don't count y twice, assuming y=y), {1/2,2/4} has two elements a=1/2 and b = 2/4. You can also say that it has 3 elements from Z (integers) - 1,2 and 4.

Comment: @RossMillikan I cannot choose b, I need to prove that it is in G and it's not *e* and inverse to itself. What I can see now that *b* both *aΔa* and *a-1Δa-1* - you can see it if you build an operation table for a group of 4 elements according to requirements. And yes, if *b* both *aΔa* and *a-1Δa-1*, then it inverse to itself. God, what a mess...

Comment: You don't choose $b$-it is just the other element of the group besides $e,a,a^{-1}$. Yes, you can just build the table. The cancellation law forces you to have each row and each column of the table containing every element.  My last two comments are just reflecting the contradiction you get if they do not.

Comment: @A.G well please, what is the answer to your question? How many elements has the set YY={y,yy,y}? (for instance the set of rational numbers {1/2,2/4})?

Comment: @A.G I know exactly what you trying to say. Each element in set count ONCE. So if there are 4 elements, it implies that they are different. But one of the main goals of the question is to show element *x* that is not *e* and also, like *e*, inverse to itself.